# Fetch array returns only one row

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```
<?php
 function comment($postid,$db_con)
{
 $commentdiv='';
 $sql="SELECT userid,time,comment FROM comments WHERE postid='$postid' LIMIT 3";
 $query = mysqli_query($db_con, $sql); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $uid=$row["userid"];
    $timecomment=$row["time"];
    $comment=$row["comment"];
$sql="SELECT username,photo FROM users WHERE id='$uid'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 $username=$row["username"];
 $photo=$row["photo"];
 $userphoto='<img src="xxx/'.$username.'/'.$photo.'">';
 if($photo== NULL){
     $userphoto = '<img src="xxx/default.png">';
 }
 $commentdiv.='<div class="xxxxxxx"><div class="yyyyyy">'.$userphoto.'</div><div class="zzzzz">'.$username.'</div><div class="vvvvv">'.$comment.'</div></div>';
}
return $commentdiv;
}
?>
```

I am new to PHP, I am trying to return 3 comments from above PHP code, but above code returns only 1 row from database, why does fetch array return only 1 row when there is more then 1 row?

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array()` by default only fetches one row. Use a loop if you want all the values..

Comment: tried using while loop,again it returns only 1 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,I use `$query2 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);` for your second query,Because it will reset first loop

```
 <?php
 function comment($postid,$db_con)
 {
 $commentdiv='';
 $sql="SELECT userid,time,comment FROM comments WHERE postid='$postid' LIMIT 3";
 $query = mysqli_query($db_con, $sql); 
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  $uid=$row["userid"];
  $timecomment=$row["time"];
  $comment=$row["comment"];
  $sql="SELECT username,photo FROM users WHERE id='$uid'";
  $query2 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);  // added new variable
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $username=$row["username"];
  $photo=$row["photo"];
  $userphoto='<img src="xxx/'.$username.'/'.$photo.'">';
 if($photo== NULL){
    $userphoto = '<img src="xxx/default.png">';
  }
     $commentdiv.='<div class="xxxxxxx"><div class="yyyyyy">'.$userphoto.'</div><div         class="zzzzz">'.$username.'</div><div class="vvvvv">'.$comment.'</div></div>';
 }
 return $commentdiv;
}
?>
```

Comment: you mean ,while loop with in while loop?

Comment: @user2982489 I updated the answer,I found the problem is in $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); ,I change the variable name

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the mysql resource variable that gives the result inside the while loop.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                                ^^^^^^ Original resource variable
```

and inside the while loop again you are using the query variable

```
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
^^^^^^ Overwriting $query inside the while loop
```

One suggestion would be to rename the variable inside the loop to something else.

Comment: @user2982489 Great! If this or any other answer helped you, kindly consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.